# Infinite limit of $\,\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ does not exist (proof)

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\;$ - prove this limit does not exist.

I will first state the definition assuming the limit $l$ is a real number. For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$, such that for all $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}\;,\;\;0<|x|<\delta\implies \left|\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)-l\right|<\epsilon$.

The limit $l$ can't be an infinite number since we have $-1<\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)<1$.

Assume for sake of a contradiction that the limit exists.
Let $\,\epsilon:=\dfrac{\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-l\right|}{2}>0$.
Then for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$, such that for all $x\in\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}\;,\;\;0<|x|<\delta\implies\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-l\right|<\frac{\left|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-l\right|}{2}\;,\;$ but then we get $\;2<1\;,\;$ which is false. A contradiction. So limit does not exist. $\square$

I am unsure whether this proof is correct or not. Should I have negated the statement instead ? Can someone help me, ideally using the method of contradiction. Thanks!

****Edit: New attempt**
Let $\epsilon:= \frac{|1-l|}{2}$. So there exists a $\epsilon > 0$ equal to $1$, such that for all $\delta > 0$, there exists a $x_0\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, where $x_0 := \frac{\pi}{2}$, such that $0<|x|<\delta\implies$, $|1-l|$ $< \frac{|1-l|}{2}$, so $2 < 1$ which is a contradiction.**

Comment: Your proof does not work because $\epsilon$ should not depend on $x$. A classical approach to this particular problem is to consider two sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, both converging to $0$ and such that there exists $a\neq b$ with $\sin(1/a_n)=a$, $\sin(1/b_n)=b$ for all $n$.

Comment: It makes no sense to define $\epsilon$ in terms of $x$.

Comment: @copper.hat That makes sense. Could I negate the statement, and then I could choose my $\epsilon$ and $x_0$ value. So let $x_0:= \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\epsilon:= \frac{1-l}{2}$?

Comment: @Surb Please check my edited proof. Is this okay ?

Comment: Your proof as it stands is not correct since for $\delta=0.00001$ it is not true that  $0<|x_0|<\delta$. Luckily that's not a terrible problem since $x_0$ isn't a place where $\sin(1/x_0)=1$ anyway. If you think about where that is true you might discover that there are such places arbitrarily close to $0$. (And also your proof doesn't show that the limit isn't $1$, since then your choice of $\epsilon$ is $0$. That's why the other proofs use **two** sequences.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe Okay thanks. Is the sequences proof basically finding two subsequences converging to distinct limits meaning that the limit must not exist ?

Comment: Yup; that's exactly what these proofs do.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe if the function was a sequence instead that’s exactly how I would solve it, but this is an analysis class and my professor taught us the definition way, so ill ask him if i would be able to use this method to

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe If the limit is $\infty$ instead of $0$, are you still able to use sequences ?

Comment: The short answer is yes, but it would be helpful for you to convince yourself of that. The point of learning real analysis is to be careful about everything, and in particular "my professor/someone on the internet told me so" is not a proof.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequences $x_n = 1/(n\pi),\; x_n \to 0\;$ and $y_n = 2/(4n+1)\pi,\; y_n\to 0$. But $\,\sin(1/x_n) = \sin(n\pi) = 0\;$ and $\sin(1/y_n) = \sin\big((4n+1)\pi/2\big) = 1\;$ for every natural $n$. Therefore the limit cannot exist.